# How to add documentation link to the Geneos Alert or Rule?

Tags: monitoring, geneos

I tried changing the email subject and destination, but not the email content, using `userdata "EMAIL_SUBJECT_ENDU"` and `userdata "EMAIL_DESTINATION"`.

Comment: Summary and actual question seem to be asking different things. What exactly are you looking for? Documentation or email?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a documentation link to an email alert then you can do it by putting it in the comment field.

Example:

```
set $(subject) concat("JobProgress - ", value, ": Batch(es) Has Stalled")
set $(comment1) "Please Refer to Knowledge Base - http://go.answers.net/12345"
if value > 0 then
  delay 1 samples
  userdata "EMAILS" "Alerts@restricted.com"
  userdata "SUBJECT" $(subject)
  userdata "LONG_COMMENT" $(comment1)
  severity critical
  run "EmailAlert"
else
  severity ok
endif
```